# SQL Query to retrieve data based on date range and also split the records based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-range

I have two tables say A and B.

```
Table A
    RecordEventStart
    RecordEventFinish
    EquipIdent

Table B
    RecordEventStart
    RecordEventFinish
    EquipIdent
    CostCode
```

I need to

1. Do a lookup of `RecordEventStart`, `RecordEventFinish`, and `EquipIdent` in table A with table B and get the `CostCode`.
2. Insert a new record to table A based on table B's date range.

Problem here is Start and Finish dates are not the same between these two tables. Table A has more granular data and Table B has less records with a bigger range.

IE Table A has dates

```
 1. 2022-05-08 06:00:00.000 to 2022-05-08 06:10:32.000  
 2. 2022-05-08 06:10:32.000 to 2022-05-08 06:15:26.000
 3. 2022-05-08 06:15:26.000 to 2022-05-08 06:15:35.000
 4. "
 5. "
 6. 2022-05-08 07:56:45.000 to 2022-05-08 08:08:55.000 
 7. 2022-05-08 08:08:55.000 to 2022-05-08 09:14:10.000
```

Where as Table B has records

```
 1.  2022-05-08 06:00:00.000  to 2022-05-08 08:44:29.000 with Code A
 2.  2022-05-08 08:44:29.000  to 2022-05-08 18:00:00.000 with Code B.
```

So here for all records of table A which falls with in start and end of table B, we need to get the corresponding code.

So for all table A records until no 6 (one that ends at 2022-05-08 08:08:55.000 ) the code will be A.

For second part of Splitting.

The Code A in table B is only until  2022-05-08 08:44:29.000. So the last record of table A needs to be split into two records.

1. one from 2022-05-08 08:08:55.000  to 2022-05-08 08:44:29.00 with Code A
2. next one from 2022-05-08 08:44:29.000 to 2022-05-08 09:14:10.000 with Code B.

Comment: What database do you use ? Is it Oracle , MySQL or.... Please share with us the code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hi, Its for MSSQL. I haven't tried any code yet, sorry.

Comment: I suggest to try.... Thanks for the update of the database.

Comment: I have tried the first part and I guess I know how to do that. I can do a join of two tables with StartDate of A between Start and End Date of B.                                                     
I can't think of a way to do the second part. Thanks!